# Confetti package animation not displaying correctly upon scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm using [Package Confetti 0.6.0](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti) `ConfettiWidget()` within `Card()`s generated in a `GridView.builder`

Upon scroll the animation stops working properly & even vanishes if I scroll too much.

[image: SliverGrid with Confetti Animation]

I thought the issue had to do with *lazy loading*, so I tried two other particle animation widgets:

1. [Particles 0.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/particles_flutter) and
2. [Animated Background 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_background)

Both of which worked fine, displaying correct animation - even through scrolling.

-> It could be just an issue with [Package Confetti 0.6.0](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti), but I think the problem might come from the way I'm initializing the `ConfettiController` and calling `.play()` method & disposing of it.

Here is my complete simplified code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late ConfettiController _controllerCenter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerCenter =
        ConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 1000));
    _controllerCenter.play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerCenter.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: new GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Center(
// 
                child: ConfettiWidget(
                  confettiController: _controllerCenter,
                  shouldLoop: true,
                ),
//
              ),
            );
          },
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

*-> I'd like to keep the animation running despite scrolling through the GridView*.

I need to use a `GridView.builder` or `GridView.count` as data within the cards will be populated with Firebase Data.